# Chinese Remainder Theorem in Rings (CRT)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the Chinese Remainder Theorem for Rings we have that the Ideals $I$ and $J$ be comaximal (i.e. $I+J=R$), then one shows that $IJ=I{\cap}J$ and proves the CRT via the first Isomorphism theorem.

Therefore it is clear that $I+J=R$ implies $IJ=I\cap J$.

My question is that

Is there a necessary and a sufficient condition for $I\cap J=IJ$, also is there an example where $I\cap J=IJ$ does not imply $I+J=R$.
(One can surely not find such examples in $\mathbb{Z}$ though.)

Edit:
Initially I had commented that such examples are not possible in $\mathbb{Z}$ by unknowingly leaving out the $(0)$ ideal ! But that is false as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, $(x)(y) = (xy)$, and every element of $(x)\cap(y)$ must be a multiple of both $x$ and $y$, hence an element of $(xy)$. However, $(x,y)\neq\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Likewise, in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, with $p$ a prime, we have $(x)(p) = (px)$ and $(p)\cap(x)=(px)$, but $(x,p)\neq\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: By the way: in $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $(0)+J = J$, $(0)(J) = (0) = (0)\cap J$ for any ideal $J$. So just pick $J\neq\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for your very Illuminating examples, I remember my Math Prof. saying something nice about ideals of form $(x,p)$ ($p$ a prime) in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So I guess they are great Ideals ( as they are an example here also!).

Comment: Basically, if both $I$ and $J$ are contained in some maximal ideal, you have no hope of having $I+J=R$. The ideals $(f(x),p)$ with $f(x)$ irreducible and primitive are maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Yes I remember my Prof. commenting that they are maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I guess therefore $\frac{\mathbb{Z[x]}}{(x,p)}=\mathbb{Z_p}$ (Since quotient by Maximal Ideals is always a field !).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a necessary and a sufficient condition for $I\cap J=IJ$

Sure:  $I\cap J\subseteq IJ$ is necessary and sufficient.

> is there an example where $I\cap J=IJ$ does not imply $I+J=R$.

How about $I=J=F_2\times \{0\}$ in the ring $R=F_2\times F_2$.  We have $IJ=I\cap J=I\neq R$.

As Arturo already pointed out in comments, if you allow one of the ideals to be zero then you *can* find an example there too.